# How to create a function with parameters in Python

Tags: python, string, list, function

I need to write a function named listsearch, which accepts a single parameter, but I don't know how.

The two lists (facts and factsK) must remain separate.

I was trying to move both print statements into separate functions and just calling it at the end because the code requires two calls, I can't figure out how to proceed.

```
#Keyword facts
facts = ["Hitler invaded Poland in 1939 which drove Great Britain and France to 
Declare war","Germany occupied Norway and Denmark and started the 'Blitzkrieg' 
against Belgium and the Netherlands","Following the attack on Pearl Harbor, the USA 
declares war against Japanese","USA begins raiding Japanese islands and bombing the 
mainland military targets","Allies invade Sicily and put Mussolini out of power","The 
Allies conduct the largest amphibious invasion ever at the Battle of Normandy where 
over  155,000 allied troops fought through the Atlantic wall to create a new front in 
France","May 8th 1945 Germany surrendered after the Soviets invaded Berlin"]

factsK = ["The deadliest battle in the War, Germany and its allies fought the Soviets 
for the city with extreme close quarters combat and direct air raids on civilians", 
"Was a German military tactic calculated to create psychological shock and resultant 
disorganization in enemy forces through the employment of surprise, speed, and 
superiority","The allies were losing the battle of France and were pushed to the port 
of Dunkirk by the Germans. The Germans halted their push for three days which allowed 
the allies to organize a retreat, more than 330,000 Allied troops were rescued","In 
1941, Just before that Sunday morning, hundreds of Japanese fighter planes descended 
on the base, where they managed to destroy or damage nearly 20 American naval 
vessels, 300 airplanes, and 2,400 Americans, Japan was hoping to cripple the American 
fleet before they entered the war. The USA declared war the day after","Codenamed 
Operation Overlord, the battle began on June 6, 1944, also known as D-Day, when some 
155,000 American, British and Canadian forces landed on five beaches along a 50 mile 
stretch of the heavily fortified coast of France’s Normandy region, creating a second 
front.D-Day was known as the beginning of the end of the War.","The liberation of 
Paris occured in 1944 where French Liberation forces staged an uprising against the 
Germans while the Americans were quickly approaching. Once the American army arrived 
in the city the German Garrison commander Dietrich von Choltitz, surrendered to the 
French allowing them to have the city again","The battle of Berlin occured in 1945 
and was one of the last major offensives in the war. The Soviets successfully 
encircled the city, The Germans refused to surrender, but the Soviets were too 
overpowering for the remaining troops. Hitler ended up committing suicide and the 
remaining German troops were captured or killed. The Nazis officially surrendered a 
week later on May 9th"]

User = input(("Keyword or date "))

Dates = ["1939","1940","1941","1942","1943","1944","1945"]

Keywords =["Stalingrad","Blitz","Dunkirk","Pearl Harbor","D-Day","Paris","Berlin"]

for D in Dates:
  if D == User:
    print(facts[Dates.index(D)])
def listSearch ():
  for K in Keywords:
    if K == User:
      print(factsK[Keywords.index(K)])
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "I need to use that to create 2 calls".  A good way to clarify what you're trying to do would be to give an example of how you need to call the function and what result you want to get.

Answer (score 1):

You're making it harder than it needs to be.  What is the variable in that function?  It's the date or keyword to search for.  So, that's what the parameter should be.

```
def listSearch(key):
  if key in Dates:
    return facts[Dates.index(key)]
  elif key in Keywords:
    return factsK[Keywords.index(key)]
  else:
    return None

User = input(("Keyword or date "))
print(listSearch(User))
```

It would be a much better design to combine `Dates` and `facts` into a dictionary, with the year as the key, so you could do a direct lookup without using `index`.  Same applies to `Keywords` and `factsK`.  Your function is simulating what a dictionary is designed to do.

Comment: Doesnt really help with my requirements for a call and I cant use that "return None" but thanks for some tips

Comment: Why can't you use "return None"?  What do you expect to do if they give you a key that is not present in either list?  And I don't know what you mean by "for a call".  You haven't told us anything about your requirements.  We can't read your mind.

Comment: I tried editing the post to clarify criteria to the best of my ability. The "call" is the function defined in def() but I cant figure out how to incorporate my print function into the def()